# proper position of 'only' in this sentence

Tags: adverb-placement

This is from [a webpage](https://ekja.org/journal/view.php?number=8734).

> However, the DSA was **only** seen in ultrasonographic images in the 7
> patients of IT group.

If the author meant that the DSA was seen in IT group but not in the other group, I wonder if the 'only' is at proper position in the sentence.

If I rewrite the sentence as follows, will it be inappropriate?

*However, the DSA was seen in ultrasonographic images in the 7 patients of IT group only.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both positions are acceptable.  I prefer the original. It is generally better to place modifiers close to the word that they modify.  In this case "only" modifies "seen", so it's better to put it next to "seen".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: **Only** is a relentless creeper. It tends to creep towards the start of a sentence when it's intended to modify something towards the end. (**I only saw Mary at the party that was held on the island last week just before I left.**)

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you very much.